# Что есть файловая система

Tags: файловая-система

Стала интересна файловая система. В определениях приводится скучное "это часть ОС...". Хочу понять что это такое на уровне процессов (не знаю как сказать точнее). Пишут что вот мол ФС определяет порядок записи инфы на жетский диск. А как она определяет это? Это отдельный процесс какой то или ФС это какая то сложная структура данных в ядре?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0 - читали? подходит?

Comment: никогда не понимал, зачем кидать ссылку на вики) Смысл какой? Я например не смог понять что значит "Файловая система это порядок...". Вы вот часто кодили "порядок"?) Или "часть ОС"?) Я - нет. Поэтому хочу понять приблизительно хотя бы, ФС это такая сложная структура данных с которой работает ядро или нечто иное.

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите узнать о файловой системе?

Comment: Буду ли я прав если скажу что ФС это структура данных, грубо говоря дерево, в узлаъ которого описаны всякие метаданные каждого уровня дерева. Т.е. файлы, их размеры и прочее

Comment: Такой вариант - У винды есть диск. К каждому диску привязан драйвер файловой системы. При чтении файла или папки - идет обращение к драйверу. Все данные отдает драйвер. У линукса чуть по-другому - драйвер привязывается не к диску а к ветке. И можно "накладывать" в подветке драйвера командой mount. Но данные отдает драйвер.

Comment: Под у винды есть диск понимается хард?

Comment: Если вас интерисует процесс загрузки - тут дела обстоят сложнее. Загрузчик - короткая программа, которая умеет только найти "ядро побольше"(загрузчик) (пропусил загрузчик партиции), грузится загрузчик ОS. Потом загрузчик имеет "урезанный встроеный драйвер fs" на чтение, с его помощью система позже загружает полноценный драйвер fs.

Comment: Файловая система — это в первую очередь формат. Формат, определяющий, в каком виде хранить файлы и папки и связанные с ними вещи типа прав доступа. А всякие там части ОС, драйверы, fuse и прочую дребедень можно воспринимать как инструменты для манипулирования этим форматом

Comment: Сформулируйте точнее что вы хотите от fs. это очень обширное понятие. Или для какой цели.

Comment: На кухонно-бытовом языке: файловая система — это что-то типа rar-архива, драйвер файловой системы — это WinRAR :) (А в линуксе можно даже монтировать архивы как файловую систему с помощью fuse и archivemount)

Comment: «Это отдельный процесс какой то или ФС это какая то сложная структура данных в ядре?» — возможны оба варианта, зависит от конкретной ОС и конкретной файловой системы

Comment: *определяет порядок записи инфы на жетский диск. А как она определяет это* - это заложено в драйвер файловой системы или в программу которая умеет читать фс или в ядро или (если оттолкнуться от ПК) определяется стандартами - правилами.

Comment: Файловая система - это набор байт - которые связаны между собой определенными правилами, позволяющими из нее выделить отдельные последовательности байт называемые файлами (как один из видов обьекта фс).

Comment: Всем спасибо! Прояснилось в некоторой степени

Comment: *зачем кидать ссылку на вики* - на вики сильно отличается от того что тут в комментариях?

Comment: *В определениях приводится скучное "это часть ОС...". Пишут что вот мол ФС определяет порядок записи инфы на жетский диск.* Больше никогда не читайте литературу, в которой пишется такая бредятина. Файловая система существует безотносительно к ОС. И файловая система существует даже у некоторых устройств, не являющихся накопителями.

Comment: It's written in Wikipedia! Not literature)

Answer (score 1):

Файловую систему (ФС) можно сравнить с библиотечным регистром, когда Вам нужно найти книгу вы ищете по автору нужную книгу в карточках, а когда находите, в ней указан стеллаж и полка. Кроме этого, библиотекарь ведет журнал перемещения книг.

В операционной системе файловый менеджер работает с драйвером файловой системы (который знает как с ней работать и понимает топологию). При загрузке в память считывается информация о разделах и секторах жесткого диска в соответствующую таблицу (как в библиотеке регистр). Если Вам необходимо загрузить что-то с HDD, драйвер файловой системы ищет нужное место в таблице разделов и секторов и через драйвер HDD запрашивает информацию, при этом формируются команды контроллеру жесткого диск, который предоставляет данные при этом они записываются в заданный участок памяти (буфер). После этого файловый менеджер считывает эту информацию из памяти, интерпретирует их и показывает пользователю уже папки и файлы на мониторе